# Apache ThreadsPerChild

Tags: memory, apache2

One of our third party enterprise application uses Apache 2.2.15 x86,

with a ThreadsPerChild of 1920 (default upper limit),

running on Windows 7 x64 (development machine)

Running it overnight, the commit size of Windows OS steadily creeps up, and no request is sent to Apache.

Reading 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx  ,

Questions:

1. Is it possible that an x86 process with that many threads simply costs Windows a lot of overhead and it will hit its Virtual Memory Size of 1.6GB (from Process Explorer, when httpd.exe child is spawned)
2. Have anybody experience running Apache with this many threads before (1920)

Answer (score 0):

Threading was never built to scale (IMHO). Maybe its time to look into an asynchronous request handling system? Like 'nginx'..

Comment: This is a 3rd party app, we will have to ask the vendor to use nginx instead of apache

Comment: @portoalet Is httpd.exe taking so much memory? Or is Windows taking so much memory?